# refresh a binded jtable with org.jdesktop.swingbinding.JTableBinding

Tags: java, swing, netbeans-8, beans-binding

I created a jpanel that contains a jtable binded to database table using netbeans right click -> bind -> elements and a refresh buton.
the jpanel is inside a jtabbedpane that is inside a jframe.
I want to refresh the jtable after adding or deleting elements and tired a lot of solutions that i found on google but nothing works for me.

the jpanel class:

```
public class Formations extends javax.swing.JPanel 
    public Formations() {
        }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {
        bindingGroup = new org.jdesktop.beansbinding.BindingGroup();

        FormationPUEntityManager = java.beans.Beans.isDesignTime() ? null : javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("PUfile").createEntityManager();
        formationQuery = java.beans.Beans.isDesignTime() ? null : FormationPUEntityManager.createQuery("SELECT f FROM Formation f");
        formationList = java.beans.Beans.isDesignTime() ? java.util.Collections.emptyList() : formationQuery.getResultList();
        btnRefresh = new javax.swing.ColoredButton();
        tblContenuFormations = new javax.swing.JTable(){
            public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
                return false;
            }
        };

        org.jdesktop.swingbinding.JTableBinding jTableBinding = org.jdesktop.swingbinding.SwingBindings.createJTableBinding(org.jdesktop.beansbinding.AutoBinding.UpdateStrategy.READ_WRITE, formationList, tblContenuFormations);
        org.jdesktop.swingbinding.JTableBinding.ColumnBinding columnBinding = jTableBinding.addColumnBinding(org.jdesktop.beansbinding.ELProperty.create("${theme}"));
        columnBinding.setColumnName("Col1");
        columnBinding.setColumnClass(String.class);
        columnBinding = jTableBinding.addColumnBinding(org.jdesktop.beansbinding.ELProperty.create("${Col1}"));
        columnBinding.setColumnName("Col2");
        columnBinding.setColumnClass(String.class);
        columnBinding = jTableBinding.addColumnBinding(org.jdesktop.beansbinding.ELProperty.create("${Col2}"));
        columnBinding.setColumnName("Col3");
        columnBinding.setColumnClass(String.class);
        columnBinding = jTableBinding.addColumnBinding(org.jdesktop.beansbinding.ELProperty.create("${Col3}"));
        columnBinding.setColumnName("Col4");
        columnBinding.setColumnClass(java.util.Collection.class);
        bindingGroup.addBinding(jTableBinding);
        jTableBinding.bind();
        tblContenuFormations.addPropertyChangeListener(new java.beans.PropertyChangeListener() {
            public void propertyChange(java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
                tblContenuFormationsPropertyChange(evt);
            }
        });
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(tblContenuFormations);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(this);
        this.setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(....));

        bindingGroup.bind();
    }                      

    private void btnRefreshActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                       
        //here goes the refresh code
    }                                                                                                       

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.persistence.EntityManager FormationPUEntityManager;
    private javax.swing.JButton btnRefresh;
    private java.util.List<dz.pcmax.entities.Formation> formationList;
    private javax.persistence.Query formationQuery;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private org.jdesktop.beansbinding.BindingGroup bindingGroup;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

the solutions i tried :

1

```
private void btnRefreshActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                       
            Binding g = bindingGroup.getBindings().get(0);
            g.unbind();
            g.bind();
    }
```

2

```
private void btnRefreshActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                       
            Binding g = bindingGroup.getBindings().get(0);
            g.unbind();
            g.bind();
            this.validate();
            this.repaint();
    }
```

3

```
private void btnRefreshActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                       
        org.jdesktop.swingbinding.JTableBinding jTableBinding = org.jdesktop.swingbinding.SwingBindings.createJTableBinding(org.jdesktop.beansbinding.AutoBinding.UpdateStrategy.READ_WRITE, formationList, tblContenuFormations);
        org.jdesktop.swingbinding.JTableBinding.ColumnBinding columnBinding = jTableBinding.addColumnBinding(org.jdesktop.beansbinding.ELProperty.create("${theme}"));
        columnBinding.setColumnName("Theme");
        columnBinding.setColumnClass(String.class);
        columnBinding = jTableBinding.addColumnBinding(org.jdesktop.beansbinding.ELProperty.create("${description}"));
        columnBinding.setColumnName("Description");
        columnBinding.setColumnClass(String.class);
        columnBinding = jTableBinding.addColumnBinding(org.jdesktop.beansbinding.ELProperty.create("${objectifs}"));
        columnBinding.setColumnName("Objectifs");
        columnBinding.setColumnClass(String.class);
        columnBinding = jTableBinding.addColumnBinding(org.jdesktop.beansbinding.ELProperty.create("${niveauCollection}"));
        columnBinding.setColumnName("Niveau Collection");
        columnBinding.setColumnClass(java.util.Collection.class);
        bindingGroup.addBinding(jTableBinding);
        jTableBinding.bind();
        getTopLevelAncestor().revalidate();
        getTopLevelAncestor().repaint();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
g.unbind();
g.setSourceObject(formationList);
g.bind();
```